# implement generic interface in delphi

Tags: object, oop, delphi, interface

Why in every ICRUD implementation should I instantiate the IINTERFACE interface methods?

```
type ICRUD<t> = interface
  ['{2CA41589-BEEC-4640-8E18-B2A35ECF1B2D}']
  function Create(obj: t):t;
  function Read(obj: t):t;
  function Update(obj: t):t;
  function Delete(obj: t):t;
end;

type
  TCliente = class(TPersona, ICRUD<TCliente>)
 private
  function QueryInterface(const IID: TGUID; out Obj): HResult; stdcall;
  function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
  function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
 public
  constructor Crear;
  function Create(Cliente: TCliente):TCliente;
  function Read(Cliente: TCliente):TCliente;
  function Update(Cliente: TCliente):TCliente;
  function Delete(Cliente: TCliente):TCliente;
end;
```

for every ICRUD implementation the compiler forces me to implement those methods. Is it mandatory? I use delphi 10

Comment: You can chose to derive your class from [`TInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.TInterfacedObject) to get these for free.

Comment: Why? Because all interfaces derive from `IInterface`. Is it mandatory to implement these? Yes.

Comment: Perfect then you have to inherit the class from TInterfacedObject so that this does not happen. Thank you very much!